# Algebra: Prove inequality $\sum_{n=1}^{2015} \frac1{n^3} < \frac 54$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

Can someone prove inequality (n is natural):$$\sum_{n=1}^{2015} \frac{1}{n^3} < \frac 5 4$$
I have tried some predictions like $a^3 > a(a - 1)(a - 2) $ but couldn't get anything out of them.

Comment: I presume the $n=0$ is a typo and you intended $n=1$.

Comment: @Crostul: it can but then the inequality is not fulfilled for sure ;-)

Comment: Yes i will fix it now

Comment: Did you try upper bounding the sum with integral?

Comment: I just want to say that this problem is meant to be solved by 15 to 16 year olds

Comment: It should be mentioned that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n^3}=\zeta(3)=1.2020569\dots>\frac{5}{4}$

Comment: @Mark I don't think upper bounding works, because
$$
1+\int_1^{2015}\frac{1}{x^3}\,dx=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{(2015)^2}.
$$

Comment: @ShaVulkia Much of the error collects at the beginning terms. You can get around this by splitting the sum. See my answer

Comment: @Mark I see. I'll leave my comment, because it shows why we have to split the sum.

Comment: @JMoravitz I believe your inequality is pointing the wrong way. $5/4 = 1.25$

Comment: Sure is, I think I was thinking of $6/5$.  In any case, recognizing that the sum is related to the zeta function is useful with or without the typo

Comment: @JMoravitz True and it even solves the question very directly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use (for $n \geq 2$)
$$\frac{1}{n^3} < \frac{1}{n^2(n-1)} < \frac12\frac{2(n-1) +1}{n^2 (n-1)^2} =\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{(n-1)^2} - \frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$

Write your sum as
$$1 + \frac{1}{2^3} + \sum_{2015\geq n\geq 3} \frac{1}{n^3} < \frac{9}{8} + \sum_{n\geq 3} \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{(n-1)^2} - \frac{1}{n^2}\right)
= \frac{9}{8} +\frac{1}{8} = \frac{5}{4}. $$

Answer (score 11):

Split the sum as $1 + 1/8 + \sum_{n=3}^\infty 1/n^3$

You need $\sum_{n=3}^\infty 1/n^3 \lt 1/8$.

$\sum_{n=3}^\infty 1/n^3 \lt \int_{x=2}^\infty 1/x^3 dx = 1/8$

Comment: Just noticing here that I substituted $2015$ with $\infty$. The problem still follows a fortiori

Comment: This also shows that this contest question can updated and used in perpetuity :-)

Answer (score 9):

Note that for $n>1$,

$$\frac{1}{n^3}<\frac{1}{n^3-n}=\frac{1}{2(n-1)}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^{2015}\frac{1}{n^3-1}=\frac{1}{2(1)}-\frac{1}{2(2)}-\frac{1}{2(2015)}+\frac{1}{2(2016)}=\frac{2031119}{8124480}<\frac{1}{4}$$